# Android: How to sum all the columns in a SQLite database and return 1 single variable

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sum

My objective is to sum all the columns in my database and return a variable 'total' = x amount.

Example:

```
column - food | taxi | clothes | sports 
          2       3      4         5
          6       8      0         12
          11      10     7         2
```

Then therefore the total will equate to = **70**

My original idea was to sum individual columns and finally add them together example of summing an individual column:

```
public Cursor sumFoodColumn(){
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, KEY_FOOD + "=?", new String[]{"sum(food)" + KEY_FOOD}, null, null, null, null);
    if (c !=null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

But I felt this would be a bit laborious as I've got 13 columns in my database, is there a better way around this? Preferably with only 1 query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run this query:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Sum(food) + Sum(taxi) + Sum(clothes) + Sum(sports) AS myTotal FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
```

Instead of

```
Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, KEY_FOOD + "=?", new String[]{"sum(food)" + KEY_FOOD}, null, null, null, null);
```

and get your total as

```
Cursor c = sumFoodColumn();
int total = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("myTotal"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Having looked online, it seems that you can do this.

`SELECT food, taxi, clothes, ..., SUM(food + taxi + clothes + ...) AS 'myTotal'
FROM table`

Source: http://www.codingforums.com/mysql/52471-possible-sum-values-multiple-fields-single-sql-record.html#post275266

Comment: post the relevant content of the link in your post along with explanation. or post link as a comment and delete this answer

Comment: As you wish, @Raghunandan

Comment: not my wish. this post came up in the review queue to be flagged for moderator attention which would have been eventually deleted as link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that. Seems a bit counter-intuitive to me, seeing as it's duplication of content.

Comment: that is bcoz once the link is dead some time in the future your answer will have no value. If you have any further issue regarding this site as it on meta.stackoverflow.com. You can have a discussion there.